# Переводим сообщение о невозможности единолично пометить копией вопрос после добавления метки для юзеров с золотым знаком по ней

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

**Проблема:**

При попытке добавить вопросу метку по коей есть золотой знак и после этого его пометить копией другого вопроса выскакивает предупреждение без перевода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Способ решения:**

Таки надо бы перевести.

Comment: Предлагайте варианты!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вот, набросал возможный перевод: [тык](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2815/17609)

Comment: Кстати, поздравляю с золотым знаком!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо) Жаль, только, что не подтвердилось моё предположение о возможности использования сего значка для вандализма))) И я ещё сегодня стал первым в списке за всё время по сей метке)

Comment: ссылка на перевод: [tx 7233](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/63415744)

Answer (score 2):

> В большинстве случаев золотой знак [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) позволяет вам единолично закрывать вопросы с соответствующей меткой как дубликата, а также переоткрывать их. Однако, поскольку вы редактировали метки этого вопроса, сейчас эта привилегия не сработает.

Кстати, а какие правила: именно что он сам редактировал метки, или что они в принципе были отредактированы? Где-то читал, что второе, но там же предлагалось переделать на первое.

Comment: Ну, лично я так делал: сначала добавил к вопросу метку, а потом попытался его задубликатить. Хотел проверить смогу ли я вандализмом с этим знаком заняться... Не удалось) Так что, думаю, первый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Возможный вариант перевода:

> Ваш [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) значок обычно позволяет вам единолично закрывать [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) вопросы как дубликаты и переоткрывать их. Однако, в этот раз, вы предварительно отредактировали метки вопроса и, засим, данная привилегия не сработала.